# Rails nested form not working (child parameters not passed at all)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

Model

```
`Buyer has_many :orders`
`Buyer accepts_nested_attributes_for :order`
`Order belongs_to :buyer`
```

View (`buyers#new`)

```
<%= form_for @buyer do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :orders do |o| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <%= o.label "Select your meal" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row section">
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <% ["Pasta, pesto, & pea greens (veggie)",
           "Mushroom cutlets & mornay sauce (veggie)",
           "Italian breaded pork chop",
           "Chicken kabobs with tzatziki",
        "Asian-style sweet & sour beef"].each do |m| %>
           <div class="col-xs-2 zero-padding">
             <div class="col-xs-12">
               <% image_tag "#{m}.jpg" %>
             </div>
             <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
               <%= o.radio_button :meal, m %>
               <br>
               <%= m %>
             </div>
           </div>
        <% end %>
      <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Controller (`buyers`)

```
 def new
    @buyer = Buyer.new
    @buyer.orders.build
 end

 def create
   # just to illustrate what i'm talking about, even the unsanitized parameters do not have orders_attributes
   puts params
   => {"utf8"=>"✓", "buyer"=>{"first_stripe_token"=>"tok_16zExiKQ2oHmpkBLo9y45Cv3", "delivery_instructions"=>"random", "zipcode"=>"02110", "email"=>"test@example.com", "phone1"=>"123", "phone2"=>"456", "phone3"=>"0789", "agree_tos"=>"1"}, "controller"=>"buyers", "action"=>"create"}
 end

 def buyer_params
    params.require(:buyer).permit(:first_stripe_token, :phone1, :phone2, :phone3, :zipcode, :delivery_instructions, :agree_tos, :email, orders_attributes: [:meal] )
 end
```

Routes

```
match '/ondemand/create', to: 'buyers#create', via: :post, as: "buyers"
```

Some folks have asked questions about how to permit nested attributes via strong parameters. That's not my challenge. In my case, the nested attributes somehow are completely, as you can see above where I do a `puts` on the unsanitized parameters.

help!

Comment: Perhaps an obvious question but, is anything selected/entered for the child fields?

Comment: yes a series of radio buttons I've added them in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer... but a little worried since this seems like such a common problem and I haven't seen a mention of it anywhere. So if I'm doing something totally wrong... please clue me in.

What happened is that the `orders_attributes` were not being passed on the SECOND try of a failed submission (I'm running rspec tests here). And the reason they weren't being passed is because they were nonexistent on the form. Here's why:

```
def new
  @buyer = Buyer.new
  @buyer.orders.build
end
```

In the `new` action, the form creates fields for both `buyer` and `order` because both have been initialized. But my original `create` action looked like this:

```
def create
  @buyer = Buyer.new(buyer_params)
  ...
  if @buyer.save
    redirect_to '/'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

In other words, if everything went well, and the buyer_params built out valid `buyer` and `order`, great! But if some kind of error happened, and the page re-rendered, there is no `order` object to build the form fields for!

**As a result, the answer:**

```
def create
  @buyer = Buyer.new(buyer_params)
  @buyer.orders.first_or_intialize

  if @buyer.save
    ...
end
```

The result is this:

- **If there are no errors** the first line creates both `buyer` and `order` and the second line is kind of a moot point since it will just call the just-created `order` (in my case even though I've written it as a `has_many`, realistically a `buyer` only has one `order`; even if that weren't the case, I'm not using the `order` object to do anything, so the second line does no harm)
- **If there are errors** then the second line instantiates an `order` object so that when the page is re-rendered, there is an `order` object to build fields for

Comment: Did you have accepts_nested_attributes_for in your buyer model?

Answer (score 0):

If your f.fields_for block was correct and there was data in it, then the params would be correct even if strong params decides to block them.  The fact that they don't show up in the params but other fields do show in the params makes me feel    like the problem is in your f.fields_for block.

Comment: I share that logic, but I'm struggling to figure out what the problem could be. The formatting is right... I'm using `<%=` which I know trips up lots of people. The generated html tags are right (id = `buyer_orders_attributes_0_meal_asian-style_sweet__sour_beef`)

Comment: Take a look at this old screencast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1